# Using data attribute to pass the data to a modal and use datepicker inside that modal without loosing data attributes data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm having an issue when using data attribute to pass data to a modal and use datepicker inside that modal. when i did that and as soon as i click the datepicker input all the data that i passed to the other inputs through data attribute is clearing. can any one explain how is that happening and is there a way to over come this issue?

my code as follows.

```
<i class="btn icon-md icon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_data_modal" data-bundle_id="1"></i>

<div class="modal bs-example-modal-lg inmodal" id="edit_data_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <form method="post" id="edit_form" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bundle_id" id="bundle_id" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" name="start_date" required>
                    <input type='submit' value='Save'>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    orientation: "top auto",
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        autoclose: true
});

$('#edit_data_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
        var bundle_id = button.data('bundle_id'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body #bundle_id').val(bundle_id);
});
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhLahiru/xpvt214o/817427/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have to separate properly your button from your modal. Are you sure that your related target matches your button ?
By the way, in jquery, no need to specify multiple selectors in this line :

```
modal.find('.modal-body #bundle_id').val(bundle_id); --> modal.find('#bundle_id').val(bundle_id); // Should be sufficient
```

Here is a working JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j8wzen73/6/

Comment: It's working fine until i click the datepicker input and when the datepicker popup comes other data in the inputs going missing.

Comment: I edited the JSFiddle to include the datepicker : https://jsfiddle.net/j8wzen73/10/
Let me know if something doesn't work or is not what you're expecting.

Comment: i added jsfiddle link in the question and i done as you said but i didn't solve it. can you please check it and look what i did wrong there.

Comment: Bureau are you there?

Comment: Excuse me, at work, don't have all the time I want ^^ I gonna take a look at your JSFiddle and come back to you !

Comment: i'm sorry bureau. didn't mean to rush or push.

Comment: No problem ;-)
I edited your JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j8wzen73/11/
You can replace the bind event "show.bs.modal" by "shown.bs.modal", let me know if that do what you expect.